# How to implement vertical slice architecture in C#

Tags: c#, architecture, cqrs, mediatr

I am working on a new project and I am interested in using the vertical slice architecture pattern. However, I am not sure how to implement this pattern in C#.

Can someone provide an explanation of what the vertical slice architecture pattern is and how to implement it in C#? Are there any specific libraries or frameworks that I should use to make the implementation easier?

I have read some articles and watched some videos about this pattern, but I am still a bit unclear on how to get started with it in C#. Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you read [Gary Woodfine's article about Vertical Slice Architecture with .NET](https://garywoodfine.com/implementing-vertical-slice-architecture/)?

Comment: Another good one is explained here https://code-maze.com/vertical-slice-architecture-aspnet-core/ and has the source code at https://github.com/CodeMazeBlog/CodeMazeGuides/tree/main/aspnetcore-webapi/VerticalSliceArchitecture. And a repo from Jimmy Bogart who originally came up with the idea of Vertical Slice Architecture is at https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityDotNetCore-Pages.